# Replacing nested while loop with GNU Parallel yields slow results

Tags: bash, shell, optimization, parallel-processing, gnu

Simple nested loop:

```
while read f1; do
    while read f2; do
    ipv4comb+=($f1,f2)
    done < $src2
done < $src1
```

```
$src1 has 88 lines
$src2 has 175 lines
produced output has 15400 lines
```

`$src1` is retrieved via ssh so lookup varies slightly, but, this loop usually yields:

`./run.sh  0.34s user 0.18s system 15% cpu 3.327 total`

If i replace the loop with:

`parallel -j+0 echo {1} {2} :::: $temp_ipv4 $MM_BLACKLIST_IPV4 | wc -l`

It yields:

`./run.sh  49.31s user 31.27s system 242% cpu 33.239 total`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU Parallel has an overhead of ~2-10 ms per job, so 15400 jobs in 49s is within the expected range.

There are some tricks to deal with short running jobs. They, however, do not apply to your case:
https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Speeding-up-fast-jobs